# WebDriverIO select using elements index

Tags: javascript, ui-automation, element, webdriver-io

I am using WebDriverIO to try to access (ie. getText, getAttribute, click, etc) an element after creating a list of elements. I am easily able to implement this element if I am using the `browser.element()` method, but the moment I use `browser.elements()`, I cannot access the individual objects in the array. According to the [WebDriverIO docs](http://webdriver.io/api/protocol/elements.html), I should be able to access them using the `value` property.

Here is my pseudo-code. I assumed that these two functions should return the same thing:

```
usingElement() {
  return browser.element('.someCss');
}

usingElements() {
  return browser.elements('.someCss').value[0];
}
```

When I try to use the first block of code, it works perfectly fine.. but
when I try to use the second block, it gives me an error saying `usingElements.click is not a function` or `usingElements.getText is not a function`, etc.

How can I isolate a single element object after using the browser.elements() method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you might need to use one of the below two ways:

Way 1:

```
var elmnts = browser.elements('.someCss');
var element = elmnts.value[0].ELEMENT;
browser.elementIdClick(element);
```

Way 2:

```
var element = $$('.someCss')[0];
element.click();
```

Thanks,
Naveen

Answer (score 0):

Your index reference was placed in the wrong spot. Try:

```
var myElement = browser.elements('.someCss')[0];
myElement.click();
```

You don't need to reference the `value` property, as WebdriverIO is smart enough to infer that for you.