# Unable to click on element using method: browser.click and xpath: //input[2]

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver, webdriver-io

Seem to be receiving the following exception:

```
element not visible
running chrome
Error: An element command could not be completed because the element is not visible on the page.
    at elementIdClick("0.12980231457632274-1") - click.js:20:22
```

My test us as followed:

```
    beforeEach(function() {
      browser.url("https://www.google.com");
    })
    describe('Test Google Homepage', function() {
        it('Should be able to click on im feeling lucky button', function(done) {
          browser.click('(//input)[7]');
    });
});
```

It seems the xpath is throwing the exception above even when adding a browser pause, any ideas why im receiving the exception?

Comment: zfrisch im using an xpath selector which locators the 'im feeling lucky' button.

Comment: are you adding enough wait time before locating this element? Also, I would recommend to use locators with reference to its attributes. For example: //input[@value=\"I'm Feeling Lucky\"]

Comment: I tried adding a pause but seems the same issue was present :/ my intentions was to use the number 7 as part of a loop to click on multiple button instances but unable to narrow the issue down; especially when the same locator works within the browser itself.

Comment: I don't know much about javascript with selenium but can you make sure if your syntax is correct. Shouldn't it be browser.click("(//input)[7]"); instead of single quotes?

Comment: Also tried the following still dosnt work :(

Comment: Can you share on which browser you are trying + version of it and all the versions of npmModules that you are using. Try to get the browserDriver version as well. PS: I want to add this as comment but i do not have 50 reputation.

Comment: I'm using the latest version of Chrome and mom modules.

Comment: Based on your previous comments... so in case you want to iterate through all the elements and click on multiple elements then follow the below link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51255595/webdriverio-select-using-elements-index/51259227#51259227

Comment: using wdio i was able to successfully perform click using xpath `browser.click('(//input)[7]');`

Comment: thanks Naveen, what npm dependency versions are you using?

Comment: here are the versions: 
    "webdriverio": "^4.12.0"
    "wdio-selenium-standalone-service": "0.0.10",
    "wdio-mocha-framework": "^0.5.13",

Just a note: I assume the issue might be related to chromeVersion with the chromeDriver version ... please double check that.

Answer (score 1):

Because you shouldn't be using xpath?

Try:
`browser('[aria-label="I\'m Feeling Lucky"]').click()`

Also it's much better to use named things rather than counting on the order of things in the page.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Tom, what if I intend to use the indexed number 7 as part of a loop to click on multiple elements by referencing the xpath?